# How do I remove text before a specified character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have results returned from a MySQL query that show as:

```
123456 : AA : SomeVariedTextHere
```

I need to only display the text to the right of the first colon.
The number before the first colon can vary in length and there is always a space after the first colon that I want to trim also

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` might be usable here:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' : ', -2)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: thanks for such a quick response. I've got
SUBSTRING_INDEX(table.columnName, ' : ', -2)
But that seems to return the same results i.e 123456 : AA : SomeTextHere